# Graphhopper - Override Weighting class and Integrate it in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, graphhopper

I am working on a Ruby on Rails backend that uses GraphHopper for direction APIs. I want to override the weighting class of GraphHopper for customized weighting which is explained in the following link.

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/weighting.md

Now the problem is, How can I integrate that overriden code in my Ruby on Rails backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in ruby. In a future version we'll make it customizable via https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/flexible-vehicle-profiles/3612